# How to search strings in certain files using absolute path by grep

Tags: command-line, grep

I want to search for a certain string in several files using absolute path, say that I want to find all occurrences of inheritDoc in sevral java files, I have tried the following command:

```
grep -inr \
--include /opt/li/projects/universign-copy-2/universign/universign-server/src/com/cryptolog/universign/server/HealthCheckHandler.java \
--include /opt/li/projects/universign-copy-2/universign/universign-admin-www/src/com/cryptolog/universign/admin/actions/HealthCheckAction.java \
--include /opt/li/projects/universign-copy-2/universign/universign-www/src/com/cryptolog/universign/www/action/HealthCheckAction.java \
--include /opt/li/projects/universign-copy-2/universign/universign-core/src/com/cryptolog/universign/core/HealthCheckConfiguration.java \
--include /opt/li/projects/universign-copy-2/universign/universign-core/src/com/cryptolog/universign/core/HealthCheckResult.java \
--include /opt/li/projects/universign-copy-2/universign/universign-core/src/com/cryptolog/universign/core/utils/HealthCheckUtils.java \
--include /opt/li/projects/universign-copy-2/universign/universign-core/src/com/cryptolog/universign/core/utils/HttpUtils.java \
inheritDoc
```

But that does not work. How could I possibly do this?

Comment: Have you tried including them in a file and then using `-f`?  You can even pipe in a list with `-f -` and the `<<` operator. Try `man grep` for information on grep switches.

Comment: @tudor If I include them in a file, I will not have information like this (for each file) : `HealthCheckHandler.java:32:public class HealthCheckHandler implements StreamHandler`, this result is from the normal grep -inr comand, I need the filename information

Comment: @Bohao LI : See -H option switch `grep -iHn 'needle' /path1/file1 /path2/file2 <...> /pathN/fileN` OR `grep -iHn 'needle' $(cat /list/of/files.txt)`-- Note that `--include` may be used with wildcards files selection

Comment: @cmak.fr Thanks, it works well. I looked at the "man grep" and finally realized that if we don't provide the "-r" option, "-H" is the default behavior. So "grep -in" == "grep -inH".

Answer (score 0):

While you've give a pattern of files to '--include' (which will override any of these previously excluded by an '--exclude' argument) you haven't actually listed the files you want to search. Try:

```
grep -inr inheritDoc \
/opt/li/projects/universign-copy-2/universign/universign-server/src/com/cryptolog/universign/server/HealthCheckHandler.java \
/opt/li/projects/universign-copy-2/universign/universign-admin-www/src/com/cryptolog/universign/admin/actions/HealthCheckAction.java \
/opt/li/projects/universign-copy-2/universign/universign-www/src/com/cryptolog/universign/www/action/HealthCheckAction.java \
/opt/li/projects/universign-copy-2/universign/universign-core/src/com/cryptolog/universign/core/HealthCheckConfiguration.java \
/opt/li/projects/universign-copy-2/universign/universign-core/src/com/cryptolog/universign/core/HealthCheckResult.java \
/opt/li/projects/universign-copy-2/universign/universign-core/src/com/cryptolog/universign/core/utils/HealthCheckUtils.java \
/opt/li/projects/universign-copy-2/universign/universign-core/src/com/cryptolog/universign/core/utils/HttpUtils.java
```

And check 'man grep' for more information.

Comment: Options "-r" does not work, "-r" means recursively search in sub-directories,  "-H" worked. Read the comments above.